# Dump to CSV/Postgres memory

Tags: sql, postgresql, memory, dump

I have a large table (300 million lines) that I would like to dump to a csv - I need to do some processing that cannot be done with SQL.  Right now I am using Squirrel as a client, and it does not apparently deal very well with large datasets - at least as far as I can tell from my own (limited) experience.  If I run the query on the actual host, will it use less memory?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet. You can directly dump a table to a CSV file using [**COPY**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-copy.html), and I don't think that would use much memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
COPY tablename
TO 'filename.csv'
WITH 
      DELIMITER AS  ','
      NULL AS ''
      CSV HEADER
```