# psql dumping a table and memory usage

Tags: database, postgresql, memory, dump

Hello
I would like to dump a postgres table to csv.  The database is local to the (Linux) machine on which I am working.

```
psql dev -U myusername -c "select * from control.mytable;" > mydata.csv
```

mytable is pretty large - around 120 million rows.  I am worried that this will take up way too much memory, and when I monitor with top the memory usage seems to keep increasing, and so I kill it when it reaches a certain point.  Does anyone know if this is *really* taking up a terrible amount of memory? I know that the usage reported by top can be somewhat misleading to the uninitiated, such as myself.  Are there any alternatives that won't take up so much memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768702/dump-to-csv-postgres-memory

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) to create the csv? COPY does a much better job.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it like this, the entire result set will be built up in the client.  So yes, it really is using a lot of memory.  If you want to alleviate that, use a cursor to fetch the result in batches.  Or use `COPY`, which already has a CSV mode built in.

Answer (score 1):

If you use COPY you have to goto stdout unless you run it as postgres user, then you can go directly to a file.

```
psql -U myusername dev -c "COPY  (select * from control.mytable) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER;" > mydata.csv
```